# REPLACE Function not returning the appropriate result

Tags: sql

I have the following statement:

```
(SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Role, '1', 'Approver 1'), '2', 'Approver 2'), '3', 'Approver 3'), '4', 'Approver 4') , '99', 'Commenter'), '199', 'Viewer'), '0', 'Preparer')) AS UserRole;
```

When the User Role is 199 it is replacing it with "Approver 1Commenter"

how do I edit the syntax to properly return "Viewer"?

Comment: What does column ROLE look like? Can you use a `case expression` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's add some line breaks so that we can see better which replacements are being performed:

```sql
(SELECT
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Role,
'1', 'Approver 1'),
'2', 'Approver 2'),
'3', 'Approver 3'),
'4', 'Approver 4'),
'99', 'Commenter'),
'199', 'Viewer'),
'0', 'Preparer')) AS UserRole;
```

It will first turn `199` into `Approver 199` (replacing `1` with `Approver 1`), then into `Approver 1Commenter` when it replaces `99` with `Commenter`. When the replacement of `199` is due, there is no `199` to be replaced any more. A simple hacky solution is to first replace `199`:

```sql
(SELECT
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Role,
'199', 'Viewer'),
'1', 'Approver 1'),
'2', 'Approver 2'),
'3', 'Approver 3'),
'4', 'Approver 4'),
'99', 'Commenter'),
'0', 'Preparer')) AS UserRole;
```

As you can see here, this approach is very error-prone; you need to make sure that you do replacements in the right order (if some of your needles are substrings of other needles, you need to replace the longer needles first), and you may run into problems if your replacement strings themselves contain needles (not the case *yet*).

The intention seems to be to map IDs to role names, which does not need string replacement. Design-wise, this should probably not be the responsibility of the query, but rather of the view which uses this data (which should have logic which understands these IDs). If you insist on doing the conversion from ID to readable name in SQL, I would recommend a [`CASE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)-based approach, assuming your SQL dialect permits it. Also consider creating a table to use as an ID -> role name mapping.

Comment: CASE
    WHEN Role = 0 THEN 'Preparer'
 WHEN Role = 1 THEN 'Approver 1'
    WHEN Role = 2 THEN 'Approver 2'
 WHEN Role = 3 THEN 'Approver 3'
 WHEN Role = 4 THEN 'Approver 4'
 WHEN Role = 99 THEN 'Commenter'
 WHEN Role = 199 THEN 'Viewer'
END

Comment: I tried posting it as code but was not able to do it. My apologies, but I understand your second suggestion, which I will adopt.

Comment: @RaulRodriguez for a cleaner solution in SQL, see Joel Coehoorn's answer.

Answer (score 2):

> how do I edit the syntax to properly return "Viewer"?

Check for `Viewer` **before** checking for `Commenter`.

But really, this seems like you should have a **table** for these values that you could join to. Absent that table, you can do it in the existing SQL with a [Table-Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql), like this:

```
SELECT Coalesce(RoleMap.RoleName, m.Role) As UserRole
FROM (
 -- main part of existing query
) m
LEFT JOIN (VALUES 
    (  0, 'Prepaper'),
    (  1, 'Approver 1'),
    (  2, 'Approver 2'),
    (  3, 'Approver 3'),
    (  4, 'Approver 4'),
    ( 99, 'Commenter'),
    (199, 'Viewer')   
) RoleMap(RoleID, RoleName) ON RoleMap.RoleId = m.Role
```

I use this technique on occasion in a certain vendor-supplied system I work on, where I have minimal ability to influence the schema.

This still needs some work to match up types (not clear in the original whether you have a varchar or an integer, or what options you have to influence the actual schema), but it's definitely a better path to take. See how much easier this technique is to read and adjust vs nested `REPLACE()` calls?

The concern is if there could be multiple Roles in the column, say as a comma-separated list. This would be **exceptionally poor schema design**, but it does still happen. In that case, *you can and should still use the table approach*, but you have to first separate the roles using [`String_Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), before performing the JOIN. Then you can role things back up by using [`String_Agg()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) in conjunction with a `GROUP BY` and maybe also an `APPLY`.

See an example below to transform a comma-separated list of IDs in a column into names instead.

> https://dbfiddle.uk/18BTsx0Z

Again, you can put the second mapping table inline the in SQL if needed using the technique shown above, and the comma-separated list in the SQL is poor practice in the first place (but hopefully this isn't you).